# Bootstrap modal inhibiting tab controls

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I'm trying create some bootstrap modals but I'm having an issue.

I have a web page containing the definition of a modal and some tabs such as:

```
<div id="myModal" class="modal show fade">
   <div class="modal-header">
        <h3>My Modal</h3>
   </div>
   <div class="modal-body">
       <form class="form-horizontal">

            <div class="control-group">
                 <label class="control-label">Field</label>
                 <div class="controls">
                    <input id="my-field" class="" type="text" disabled="">
                 </div>
            </div>

        </form>    
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Close</button>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="tabbable custom-tab"> 
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
        <li class="active"><a href="#tab1" data-toggle="tab">Tab1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tab2" data-toggle="tab">Tab 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tab3" data-toggle="tab">Tab 3</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="tab-content">
        <div class="tab-pane active" id="tab1">
                ........
        </div>

        etc...
    </div>
 <div>
```

When activated the modal covers the tab controls. Without the definition of the modal the tabs work fine but with the definition I cannot click on the tabs (or atleast some of them), that is the cursor doesn't change to the little hand to allow me to click on them. It's as if even though the modal is hidden it is covering the tabs. However, after activating the modal and then closing it I can then click on the tabs as normal.

Any ideas as to what is going on?

Thank you for reading.

Comment: Can you demonstrate the problem in a fiddle or using http://www.bootply.com/ ?

Comment: Thanks, bit of a newbie to bootstrap so not familiar with those options. Think it might be a little involved to extract the relevant code. I'll see what I can do.

Comment: Don't worry I think I know whats wrong.

Comment: Just wanted to bring this to your attention, I noticed that you have asked 9 questions now and have not accepted answers on any of them.  I would encourage you to go through your past questions and accept and or up-vote answers that were useful to you.  This will help out them and also help out you because users may be less inclined to answer questions from you in the future if you don't accept answers to your questions.

Comment: Ok, so I've stripped things out a little. The trouble seems to be that I want the modal to be a larger than the default and so I've changed the max-height of modal-body to 1000px. This is the thing that seems to cause my problem. Is there another way of changing the height to avoid this?

Comment: Sorry I don't think I understand, what is your current problem?  From your question `I cannot click on the tabs (or atleast some of them), that is the cursor doesn't change to the little hand to allow me to click on them.` My examples addressed this issue and I am seeing that the tabs are clickable before activating the modal.  Please be more specific on what your actual problem is and what your trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you trying to make the modal fill the whole screen? I ask this because you have omitted two divs that make up the modal: modal-dialog and modal-content. The point of the modal is to bring up another screen without having to serve another page to the browser.

I added the two missing div here http://www.bootply.com/94913, so you can see the difference from this version http://www.bootply.com/89609.

The reason you were unable to click the tabs is because the modal was called at the start instead of via a button or link. Since you omitted the two div mentioned above, this cause the modal to fill the screen and not allow access to the underlying page. Also, since the modal filled the screen, you could not simply click off of it to dismiss the modal and continue. Your only option at that point was to click the close button.

Also, a 1000px modal is not suggested as it will cause scrolling of the browser window on most viewing platforms. Unless this is being designed as a full-screen desktop only application, please plan your modals accordingly. The general rule of thumb that I use is if the modal occupies more than a quarter of the existing website, it probably deserves its own page, or should be incorporated into another section. When you introduce scrolling and modals, you have to take into account the click-off dismiss and either set the modal-backdrop to static or some other custom handling.

Answer (score 2):

I believe the issue is with your `Modal`

Take out the `show` class from your `myModal` div

```
<div id="myModal" class="modal show fade">
```

To

```
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade">
```

The show class seems to interfering with the tabs.  Take a look at this example.

http://www.bootply.com/89609

Comment: Sorry that didn't fix it. The modal isn't show to start with it's activated by

Comment: data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" when I click on an table row shown in the tab that's initially active. It's just at that point I can't click on the other tabs. AFter the modal is closed I can then click on those tabs.

Comment: I'm not sure that I understand.. The only reason the modal was showing was because I called it via jQuery.  Look at this example  http://www.bootply.com/89612 Is that not what your looking for?

Comment: Mmmm, yes that's pretty much it. Not sure why it's not working on mine though.

Comment: @PaulN Look at my latest example http://bootply.com/89612 you will see that you can click on the tabs right away.

Comment: Because of your class="show" which I noted in my answer. It should look like `class="modal fade"` instead of `class="modal show fade"`

Comment: Yes, I see that, which is the behaviour I'm looking for. I think I'm goint to have strip mine back to match yours and then build it up again. Thanks.

Comment: Ok, so I've stripped things out a little. The trouble seems to be that I want the modal to be a larger than the default and so I've changed the max-height of modal-body to 1000px. This is the thing that seems to cause my problem. Is there another way of changing the height to avoid this?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/39923/discussion-between-pauln-and-trevor)

Comment: @PaulN please mark this answer as accepted if it answered your question, otherwise give feedback on what is not resolved. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just add the "display:none;" to your modal div style :

```
<div id="myModal" class="modal show fade" style="display:none;">
```

This way it is out of the way until you want to access it.